# Oracle External Table - No Rows Selected

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I've created an external table using the following definition

```
    CREATE TABLE EXT_TABLE (CID NUMBER, CNAME VARCHAR2(20), FEES NUMBER)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY TEST_DIR
ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     (
     CID INTEGER,
     CNAME CHAR(20),
     FEES INTEGER
     )
     )
     LOCATION ('DATA.TXT'))
     REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

table has been created. But, when i try to select data from table, I don't find any records

```
  SQL> select * from ext_table;

no rows selected
```

I've made sure directory and table have sufficient privileges for the user.
The data in text file;

```
1,JAVA,300
2,LINUX,400
3,ORACLE,400
4,EXCEL,500
```

Comment: Though the error code and messages are ambiguous with few other questions, I am unable to get the error fixed based on answers from them.

Answer (score 0):

`RECORD` is not the keyword you should use here.

it must be `RECORDS`.

Use this:

```
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @Tejash, I tried that, it gave a different error saying "number" was a bad identifier, so I changed the number to integer, then it said reject limit reached, so I went ahead and added reject limit unlimited. Now table is created and when i select data, it says no rows selected

Comment: modified question accordingly